# Yesod forms with page flow

Tags: forms, rest, haskell, session-state, yesod

Certain forms are too complicated to have them fit on one page. If, for example, a form involves large amounts of structured data, such as picking locations on a map, scheduling events in a calendar widget, or having certain parts of a form change depending on earlier input, it is of value to be able to break up a certain form over multiple pages.

This is easy to do with dynamic web pages and Javascript, as one would simply create a tab widget with different pages, and the actual submitted form would contain the whole tab widget and all of its input fields, yielding a single `POST` request for the entire operation.

Sometimes, however, it takes a long time to generate certain input fields; they might even be computationally intensive even after the page has been generated, taxing the low-end computer user's browser. Additionally, it becomes difficult or impossible to create forms that adapt themselves based on earlier input.

It therefore becomes necessary to split up a certain form over multiple full page requests.

This can prove to be difficult, especially since the first page of a form will `POST` to `/location/a`, which will issue a redirect to `/location/b` and requested as `GET` by the client. Passing the stored form data from `POST /location/a` to `GET /location/b` is where the difficulty lies.

Erwin Vervaet, the creator of Spring Web Flow (A subproject of the Spring framework, mostly known for its dependency injection capabilities) once wrote [a blog article](http://ev9d9.blogspot.se/2009/11/page-flow-challenge.html) demonstrating this functionality in said framework, and also comparing it to the Lift Web Framework which implemented [similar functionality](http://demo.liftweb.net/wiz2). He then presents a challenge to other web frameworks, which is further described in [a later article](http://ev9d9.blogspot.se/2009/11/page-flow-challenge-clarification.html).

How would Yesod face this problem, especially considering its stateless REST-based nature?

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, there's no pre-built solution to this in existence yet (that I'm aware of at least). And I'm not familiar with how the other frameworks mentioned solve the problem. So what I say here is pretty much conjecture. I'm fairly certain it would work, however.

The crux of the issue here is encoding page A's POST parameters into the GET request for page B. The simplest way to do that would be to stick page A's POST parameters into a session variable. However, doing so would break navigation pretty thoroughly: back/forward wouldn't work at all as described.

So we come back to REST: we need to encode the POST parameters into the request itself. That really means putting the information in either the requested path, or the query string. And the query string probably makes the most sense.

I'd be concerned about putting the raw POST parameters into the query string, as that would allow any proxy server to easily snoop the contents. So I'd like to leverage the existing cryptography from clientsession. In other words, we'll stick a signed, encrypted version of the previous form submission in a query string parameter.

To make it a bit more concrete:

- User goes to page A via GET.
- User submits page A via POST.
- Server validates form submission, gets a value, serializes it, encrypts/hashes it.
- User is redirected to page B as a GET, with a query string parameter containing the encrypted/hashed value from page A.
- Continue this process as many times as desired.
- On the final page, you can decrypt the query string parameter and have all of the form submissions.

This looks like it would be a fun add-on package to write if anyone's interested.

Comment: This solution would require writing lots of "manual" forms, one for each page, that packs and unpacks values and dispatches them (for example for the situation where the user is on Page 2, having entered stuff on Page 1, and presses an HTML-based back link, the link `GET /page1` must include the **updated** form state preferably **sans Javascript-involvement**). Without a ton of magic in the `yesod-form` package, where there was an explicit `AForm` constructor keeping track of pages and parameter parsing, and some magical `FormFooPage<#>R`'s, this solution seems "unimplementable".

Comment: If necessary, of course, I'll hand-roll this implementation as the idea is very feasible, but Yesod won't be able to help me at all in that case, even with form field rendering.

Comment: I wasn't discussing how to make a nice, user-friendly API out of this, just how the internals would work. I would imagine that, at a high level, we'd have something where you could provide a tuple of the individual forms you want run, and Yesod would automatically handle the book-keeping for you, ultimately providing you with a tuple of results. It's definitely an interesting question, but I think the mailing list might be better for hashing out the details than 600 character comments :).

Comment: Oh, I wasn't pushing for a centralized implementation. I was just observing that it would be difficult as-is even if I tried to implement something using existing components...